# Slow UDP data receiving on Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, udp, streaming

I am trying to stream a video sent by a camera over the Wi-Fi. The official app has good performance and I wonder why my implementation lags.

The camera sent data over UDP and each packet contains one JPEG image + some metadata.

My question here is about the general structure of my infinite loop. Do you think this code could be more efficient and/or more reliable?

I am also getting a lot `poll timed out error` (the frequency depends on the timeout I put on the socket of course).

Also, the `run` method is executed within a background thread.

```java
override fun run() {

        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND)

        socket = null
        try {
            socket = DatagramSocket(udpPort)
            socket?.soTimeout = 1000
        } catch (error: Exception) {
            error.message?.let {
                Log.e("$TAG/run", "Can't create the socket for streaming: ${error.message}")
            }
        }

        socket?.let { socket ->

            // The camera sends each image in one UDP packet, normally between 25000 and 30000 bytes.
            // We set 35000 here to be safe.
            var udpPacketBuffer: ByteArray
            var currentFrame: Bitmap?

            var receivedPacket: DatagramPacket? = null

            currentFrame = null
            while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                try {

                    udpPacketBuffer = ByteArray(35000)
                    receivedPacket = DatagramPacket(
                        udpPacketBuffer, udpPacketBuffer.size,
                        address, udpPort
                    )

                    socket?.receive(receivedPacket)

                    imageExecutor.submit {

                        currentFrame = getImage(receivedPacket)
                        currentFrame?.let { currentFrame ->
                            // Display the image in the app.
                            // Commenting this does not remove the lag.
                            imageConsumer(currentFrame)
                        }
                    }

                } catch (error: Exception) {
                    error.message?.let { Log.e("$TAG/run", it) }
                }
            }
        }

        imageExecutor.shutdown()
        socket?.close()
        Thread.interrupted()
    }

    private fun getImage(receivedPacket: DatagramPacket): Bitmap? {

        var currentFrame: Bitmap? = null
        try {
            var imageData = getImageData(receivedPacket)
            currentFrame = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.size)

        } catch (error: Exception) {
            error.message?.let { Log.e("$TAG/getImage", it) }
            onLoading?.let { it() }
        }

        return currentFrame
    }

    private fun getImageData(receivedPacket: DatagramPacket): ByteArray {
        val udpData = receivedPacket.data
        // The camera adds some kind of header to each packet, which we need to ignore
        val videoDataStart = getImageDataStart(receivedPacket, udpData)
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(udpData, videoDataStart, receivedPacket.length)
    }

    private fun getImageDataStart(receivedPacket: DatagramPacket, udpData: ByteArray): Int {
        var videoDataStart = 130

        // The image data starts somewhere after the first 130 bytes, but at last in 320 bytes
        var k = 130
        while (k < 320 && k < receivedPacket.length - 1) {
            // The bytes FF and D8 signify the start of the jpeg data, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format
            if (udpData[k] == 0xFF.toByte() && udpData[k + 1] == 0xD8.toByte()) {
                videoDataStart = k
            }
            k++
        }
        return videoDataStart
    }
```

Comment: did you figure it out the reason of delay?